# Trouble writing the correct mysql query (COUNT)

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following mysql table:

```
    Person   Car      Color
     ------------------------
     1       Audi     Blue
     2       BMW      Red
     3       Honda    Blue
     4       Audi     Red
     5       Audi     Yellow
     6       Audi     Blue
```

I am trying to select the following:

The persons who owns an Audi and their colors are found less than 3 times across everyone.

The results should be Person 4 & 5.

I tried the following query but I am not getting the desired results:

```
SELECT Person FROM CarTable
WHERE Car = "Audi"
GROUP BY Color
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

What would be the correct query to achieve what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Person
FROM CarTable t1
JOIN (SELECT color, COUNT(*) c
      FROM CarTable
      GROUP BY color
      HAVING c < 3) t2
USING (color)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there other solution other than using derived table?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a query that uses a subquery that identifies the colors first

```
select person 
from cars 
where car='Audi' 
      and color in (select color 
                    from cars 
                    group by color 
                    having count(color) < 3);
```

Comment: Can such query have impact on speed? I tried the same logic on a big Database (200k + records) and it seems to take forever to run.

Comment: @PeterLur when the number of records are huge a query that contains a subquery or join usually has performance impacts than the ones without. It depends on what execution plan the DBMS converts it to, indexes etc.

Comment: My experience is that MySQL is pretty poor at optimizing IN compared to JOIN. But my servers are running MySQL 5.1, maybe they've improved it in later versions.